# Can't set namespace with class extending Exception

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that extends the Exception class.

```
namespace App\CustomException;

class FileException extends Exception {

    public function __construct($name) {
        parent::construct($name);
    }
}
```

I get a fatal error: `Fatal error: Class 'App\CustomException\Exception` on the line for the class that extends `Exception`.

I want to use a namespace for my custom exception messages so that I can import them easily in a another file, like `use App\CustomException`.

Why am I getting an error and how do I fix this? I don't get an error when I remove `extend Exception`, so I'm guessing this has something to do with the parent class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
class MyException extends \Exception {}
// Add / before Exception ;)
```

Comment: I actually did try that after googling...and it did not work. ...I just tried it again, and it worked! What happened?

Comment: I don't know... If you use cache or sync(ftp,...)... perhaps you've lost your change...